# Ionic Capacitor storage GET is not working as expected

Tags: ionic-framework, storage, capacitor

I am using [capacitor storage](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage) where I am trying to set user token. When I set token and after that I am trying to access it, everything works fine.

```
public async getToken(){
        Storage.get({
            key: 'token'
        }).then(r => r.value)
    }


public async setToken(token: string): Promise<void> {
        return await Storage.set({
            key: 'token',
            value: token
        }).then(() => this.getToken())
    }
```

but when I try to access it before setting, my app stucks becouse of infinite loop.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F80oe.png)

anyone met with something like this ?

Comment: you need to re-organise your code

Comment: So the reason is that item is not stored and it is trying to find it ? Becouse i am trying to store auth token so it is not always stored before accessing.

Comment: Review your code, you should handle the fact that the data its looking for might not be present there, so needs to be handled. 

Then you fix the error why its not being stored. Also instead of trying to store an auth token, try to store some dummy text, see if it works, then proceed from there.